# How to add value of text box and multiple dynamic textbox and dropdown list in two tables?using ajax, jquery in mvc?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have two tables
1- Employee table having column - eid and Name
2- project table having 4 column- pid,Department,Project,eid
(eid is foreign key in 2nd table)
and I have textboxe and buttons in html and I am appending drop down list and textbox

```
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

  <input type="button" value="Add" id="add" class="btn btn-success" />

  <div class="row" id="show">
  </div>

  <input type="button" value="Save" id="save" class="btn btn-success" />

  @section Scripts {
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 1;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add").click(function () {
            $("#save").show();
            $("#show").append("<div class='col-sm-6' id='s" + count + "'>"+
                "<select id = 'sel' name='sel'> " +
                "<option disabled selected> -Select department-</option>"+
                "<option >Software</option>" +
                "<option >Hardware</option>" +
                "<option >Media</option>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class= 'col-sm-6'>" +
                "<input type='text' id='pro' name='pro' />"+"</div>");
        }); 
        count++;
```

I have to save all these values in tables...there one employee can have more than one project as well in more than one department. I know how to post values in first table using ajax and I did that but I don't know how to send append feilds values in second table.. please help.
here what I did to send values in first table-

```
        $("#save").click(function () {
            var data = {
                'Name': $("#Name").val(),
            };
            $.ajax({
                'url': ' @Url.Action("SaveVal")',
                'type': 'post',
                'datatype': 'json',
                'data': data,
                'success': function (fun) {
                    if (fun.status) {
                        alert(fun.msg);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(fun.msg);
                    }
                },
                'error': function () {
                    alert("task fail");
                }
            });
```

here what I did in controller-

```
    ProjectEntities pro = new ProjectEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SaveVal(Employee emp)
    {
        try
        {
            pro.employees.Add(db);
            pro.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { status = true, msg = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { status = false, msg = "There is some error!" }, 
         JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a member of emp which is a Project?

Comment: In emp eid is primary key which is foreign key in project

Comment: I understand that you have that relation, but I wonder how your ORM objects are looking alike.